# Queries containing special characters

Tags: soql

We have a number of users who will write their case notes in Word, then paste them into Salesforce. We have now implemented a custom search on case notes (and a few other fields) and have found a problem.

- Text pasted from word = "Mary O’Connor"
- Text typed into salesforce = "Mary O'Connor"

Querying "`select CaseNotes__c from Case where CaseNotes__c like 'Mary O'Connor'`" does not return the record with Mary O’Connor (with the curly quotes).

Any suggestions other than a) getting them to turn off curly quotes in word or b) getting them to always search on only the part of the word that does not contain the apostrophe?

(I think that EM dashes, umlats accents and any other special characters will be the same. Querying where CaseNotes__c like 'Amelie' would probably not return Amélie either).

Comment: Non Salesforce peeps on twitter have answered with two excellent suggestions. Either put a trigger on the field to replace the special characters before saving the record, or query the field with a regex substitution. Both will probably work - I like the trigger idea best. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a good idea to use a [`escapeSingleQuotes(...)`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm) method of the `String` class:

> Returns a String with the escape character () added before any single
>   quotation marks in the String

```
// The search query
String query;

// Now creating a dynamic SOQL
query += 'select CaseNotes__c from Case ';
query += ' where CaseNotes__c like \''+  String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchString) + '\'';
```

So in your case the query will looks like:

```
select CaseNotes__c from Case  where CaseNotes__c like 'Mary O\'Connor'
```

Comment: That still won't find Mary O(curlyquote)Connor because it is not a character that needs to be escaped, but I like your thinking. Thanks.